# How to use where condition on all array indexes in mongodb laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I am trying to fetch data from mongodb using where condition on product name.
But problem is I am having index array of product. Can anyone please help me on how to use where condition on all array indexes in laravel. Any help will be appreciated.

```
[product] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 30
                        [merchant_id] => 11
                        [code] => 0
                        [name] => Lumia 720

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 21
                        [merchant_id] => 11
                        [code] => 0
                        [name] => Samsung galaxy

                    )

            )
```

Comment: Use `foreach($array['product'] as $key => $val){ //condition here }`

Comment: Is it possible to use foreach inside query??

Comment: Can i see your code?